# I need the old plugin jdo for eclipse

Tags: java, web, eclipse-plugin, persistence, jdo

Could anyone provide the old jdo plugin for Eclipse (must be the old, can not be the current DataNucleus). If someone does not have, but know where to find, please provide the link. Note: The site http://www.jpox.org which provided this plugin, but is now the Datanuclues, which does not have the plugin JPox.

I am trying to solve the problem below, if anyone has a solution, please answer.

Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jdo.JdoUsageException: The class "br.com.omd.ouvidoria.logica.domain.Ouvidoria" is not Persistence-Capable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data for the class is not found.; nested exception is org.jpox.exceptions.ClassNotPersistenceCapableException: The class "br.com.omd.ouvidoria.logica.domain.Ouvidoria" is not Persistence-Capable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data for the class is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JPOX` was open source, and its code still exists on SourceForge. "ide.eclipse" is the project you need. 
https://sourceforge.net/p/jpox/code/HEAD/tree/tools/

But then its downloads are also still available on SourceForge.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/jpox/files/jpox-eclipse/

But then this, on its own, will not solve the problem you have there. You simply have not enhanced your classes. And the `DataNucleus` tools provide ways for you to enhance your classes, so no idea why you are even thinking of using something so out of date

Comment: Thank very much Neil Stockton, I need the JPox out of date because I'm working in legacy project. Best regards ;-)